# Is the tag for Pots a synonym of the tag for Containers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noticed there's a tag: [pots](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pots)

> Plant containers that are typically round

and a tag: [containers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers).

> Plant pots and boxes that hold soil and growing plants.

It sounds to me like the tag for Pots should be a synonym for the tag Containers. Especially since the tag wiki for Containers specifically mentions it includes pots, and the tag wiki for Pots calls them containers.

Also, one of the synonyms for [containers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers) is [potting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potting)

Is there something about pots that I don't know about that would make them different from containers?

Comment: I was asking in the chat the same thing. [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17176236#17176236)

Answer (score 5):

Because all pots are containers, but not all containers are pots, I tend to agree. The tag for [pots](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pots) should be a synonym for the tag [containers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers).

Comment: I removed the synonym between [pot] and [pots], and created one between [pots] and [containers].